# How to implement a C++ Trie with multiple variables

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, trie

I need to implement a Trie data structure to store **first name**, **last name** and **age**.

The assignment says: *"Once the path to the last name is established the first and last name and age of the person is stored in a struct variable of type Person. It is pointed to by the Trie."*
I don't understand exactly what this means, and all examples I found online only use one string instead of multiple variables (such as first name, last name and age).

I managed to get it working for one string of characters. But I don't know how to store the last name and age appropriately.

Code examples would be greatly appreciated.

**Some other requirements/specifications:**

- The name strings are no longer than 10 characters.
- Assume that all names are lowercase.
- Accept only a-z letters (no punctuation, no hyphens, no accents, etc).
- Search a Trie for a specific person's record based on last name only.
- Search a Trie for a specific person's record based on first name + last name.
- Delete A Person´s Record. Allow for people with same names do exist in the Trie.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;


struct Trie
{
    struct Trie* child[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    bool endOfString; // True if the node represents end of word
};

Trie* createNode(void)
{
    Trie* trieNode = new Trie;
    trieNode->endOfString = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
        trieNode->child[i] = NULL;

    return trieNode;
}

void insert(Trie* root, string key)
{
    cout << "Inserting key: " + key << endl;
    Trie* current = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = key[i] - 'a';

        if (!current->child[index])
            current->child[index] = createNode();

        current = current->child[index];
    }

    current->endOfString = true; // Last node as leaf
}

bool search(Trie* root, string key)
{
    cout << "Searching for key: " + key + "...";

    Trie* current = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = key[i] - 'a';

        if (!current->child[index])
            return false;

        current = current->child[index];
    }

    return (current != NULL && current->endOfString);
}

bool isEmpty(Trie* root) // check if root has children
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
        if (root->child[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}

Trie* remove(Trie* root, string key, int depth = 0){
    
    if (!root) // If tree is empty, return null
        return NULL;

    if (depth == key.size()) // If the last character is being processed
    {
        if (root->endOfString)
            root->endOfString = false;

        if (isEmpty(root))
        {
            delete (root);
            root = NULL;
        }

        return root;
    }

    int index = key[depth] - 'a';
    root->child[index] = remove(root->child[index], key, depth + 1); // Recur for child

    if (isEmpty(root) && root->endOfString == false) // If the root has no children
    {
        delete (root);
        root = NULL;
    }

    return root;
}

int main()
{
    Trie* root = createNode();

    insert(root, "john");
    insert(root, "jane");

    // Search test 1
    if (search(root, "john"))
        cout << "[FOUND]" << endl;
    else
        cout << "[NOT FOUND]" << endl;
    // Search test 2
    if (search(root, "jane"))
        cout << "[FOUND]" << endl;
    else
        cout << "[NOT FOUND]" << endl;
    // Search test 3 (Item does not exist)
    if (search(root, "jo"))
        cout << "[FOUND]" << endl;
    else
        cout << "[NOT FOUND]" << endl;

    // Removal test 
    remove(root, "john");
    if (search(root, "john"))
        cout << "[FOUND]" << endl;
    else
        cout << "[NOT FOUND]" << endl;  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: the fields should go into `struct Trie`. Currently, the only bit of information it has is `bool endOfString`: does a string end there? Add the three required fields alongside that.

Comment: **Obviously, you have to do your homework**.  If your teacher gave you an homework, then it is usually means that you have already learned most of what you need to be able to do the homework. So review your course notes.

Comment: Thank you for that, @Gassa. I wasn't sure. I will try again with the new fields in the `struct Trie`.

Comment: @Phil1970, There is only a single power point presentation on this type of data structure in my course material. In that presentation, there is one example that uses one string. I have also searched online and could not find any examples that use more than one variable.